# Home link or button

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to create a button/link on an html page via html/javascript/... that goes to the url stored as 'homepage'.
  It should do the same as clicking on the home icon in internet explorer.

Regards

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 2):

**No**, it is not possible.
The users 'homepage' is not accessible due to privacy reasons.